# Black line between 2 images while using append on imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two files;

- 1.jpg = 14000x2800 pixels
- 2.jpg = 2800x128 pixels

I use the following command:

`...\convert.exe -auto-orient -quality 100 -append "1.jpg" "2.jpg" "out.jpg"`

The goal is to merge the images together on the vertical axis, and it works great but now I need to add a straight horizontal black line between images (line's length should be the biggest file's length, meaning from left to right) while appending.

Is there any way to do that without a second command?

Easier description with MSPaint skills

[image: Easier description with MSPaint skills]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
magick 1.jpg 2.jpg -size "%[fx:u.w>v.w?u.w:v.w]x10" xc:black -swap 2,1 -append result.png
```

That says... *load `1.jpg` and `2.jpg`. Define the width for the canvas we create next as "whatever is the wider of `1.jpg` (referred to as `u`) and `2.jpg` (referred to as `v`)" by 10 pixels tall. Create a black canvas that size. Now swap the order so that the canvas we just created is between the two images. Append all 3 images and save.*

That gives you one of these, depending which one you load first:

[image]   [image]

If you want the unfilled, white background area beside the narrower image to be, say magenta, use:

```
magick -background magenta 1.jpg 2.jpg -size "%[fx:u.w>v.w?u.w:v.w]x10" xc:black -swap 2,1 -append result.png
```

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, image processing, wider, widest, taller, tallest, match existing image width, match height.